# PHP force close a file even though it is used in another process

Tags: php, windows, unlink

I have an API to compress PDF files.When the API fails i need to unlink that file and i got "permission denied" error.How to force close a file even though it is used in another process?. I am using Windows platform.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['researchfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path1))
{
    /** Call API to compress PDF **/
    $API_response = compress_now($target_path1);
    /** compress failed.File is still in use **/
    if(isset($API_response->error))
    {          
     unlink($target_path1);/** Couldnot unlink.Permission denied  **/
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain your question ans show us how you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have attached my code snippet. @siddiqui

Comment: What is the permission of your file??

Comment: Its not about permission.I need to close a file that is already in use